# Accessing specific storage account id created using terraform module

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating an infrastructure with terraform modules. Some of the common and repeatitive infra are created using module
and other resources are created independently outside of the module. The structure of my code is described as below.

-terraform\module\storage.tf

-terraform\main.tf

-terraform\mlws.tf

This is my code for /module/storage.tf where I am createing a storage account like this

```
  resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                      = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name       = var.rg_name
  location                  = var.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "GRS"
  min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
}

module "m1" {
  source                     = "./modules"

  storage_account_name       = "m1storage"
  rg_name                    = "rg1"
  location                   = "USCentral"

}

module "m2" {
  source                     = "./modules"

  storage_account_name       = "m2storage"
  rg_name                    = "rg2"
  location                   = "USCentral"
}

module "m3" {
  source                     = "./modules"

  storage_account_name       = "m3storage"
  rg_name                    = "rg3"
  location                   = "USCentral"
}

resource "azurerm_machine_learning_workspace" "mlws" {
  name                    = "mlws"
  location                = ""USCentral"
  resource_group_name     = "mlws-rg1"
  application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.mlops_appins.id
  key_vault_id            = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  storage_account_id      = **<Mandatory to be filled>**
  container_registry_id   = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.m2
  ]
}
```

The code for storage account is under \terraform\module\storage.tf, The code for calling the module is under \terraform\main.tf, The code for machine learning workspace is under \terraform\mlws.tf.

Since my mlws.tf code is outside the module but it need to be associated with storage account id created under module m2 in above code.
I am struggling to fetch the id of "m2storage" storage account. Can you please provide solution on how can I access  the id of specific storage account created through module and attach it with my code which is outside the module.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it normally works. You run module `m2` and it should give output something like this (should include `storage_account_id`):

```
output "storage_account_id" {
  description = "M2 storage account id."
  value       = m2.storage_account.storage_account_id
}
```

Now you have the output and you want to use it you will refer to it as:

```
resource "azurerm_machine_learning_workspace" "mlws" {
  name                    = "mlws"
  location                = ""USCentral"
  resource_group_name     = "mlws-rg1"
  application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.mlops_appins.id
  key_vault_id            = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  storage_account_id      = module.m2.storage_account_id
  container_registry_id   = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.m2
  ]
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not working. I am getting error like this "No module call named "m2" is declared in module.m1". Same error is repeated thrice for all 3 module calls. I did try out earlier but I wasn't sure how to retrieve the specific storage account id.